# Selecting multiple xpath elements using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, ide

I am trying to select multiple elements using xpath in Selenium IDE.  The query i am using is

```
//*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")]
```

This works for the first element, but there are 8 on the screen that I am trying to target.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

*Edit - here is the HTML copied over from Firebug.  I extended the product, but the left the other ones minimized for space.  The first four products are gift announcements (the functionality I am testing)) and the last 4 are actual products.  For the record, what I am trying to target is -

`<td class="item-address">`
`<select id="address_menu_71740515" name="address_71740515">`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<tr id="item_71740515" class=" odd gift_cont">
<th class="sub">
<td class="product">1 x Gift Announcement (Physical)</td>
<td>
<td class="item-address">
<select id="address_menu_71740515" name="address_71740515">
</td>
<td class="price">$0.00</td>
<td class="price">$0.00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gift_sep">

<script type="text/javascript">
<tr id="item_71740511" class=" gift_cont">
<tr class="gift_sep">

<script type="text/javascript">
<tr id="item_71740507" class=" odd gift_cont">
<tr class="gift_sep">

<script type="text/javascript">
<tr id="item_71740503" class=" gift_cont">
<tr class="gift_sep">

<tr id="item_71740495" class=" odd">

<tr id="item_71740487" class=" ">

<tr id="item_71740499" class=" odd">

<tr id="item_71740491" class=" ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not possible to do this way in Selenium. Many of its commands intended to work with exact one element. Although you can do it another way, just clarify your question what do you need exactly?

Now it seems that I understood what you are doing. You have `selects` inside `<td>`.
`//*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")][1]` allows to select only from siblings, but your selects are obviously not those.

If you have all of them in one table then you can slightly change expression, e.g.:

```
//tr[contains(@id, 'item_')][1]/descendant::select 
//tr[contains(@id, 'item_')][2]/descendant::select
```

Comment: I am trying to select from 8 different dropdown boxes.  The default target for each of the address selection boxes is id=address_menu_71740043 (with a varying number string).  I had used the previous xpath target before, so I had assumed there might be a way to select the first, second, third, and so on.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @kroe761 , first of all check whether this is a typo in question or in you actual code, you have not closing bracket `]`

Comment: @kroe761, second you can try to select only one element by using  sequence number, e.g. `//*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")][8]`

Comment: Yes, there was a typo.  Thanks :-)

//*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")][1] did target the first element, but //*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")][2] did not target the second element.  I think i can make it work by selecting just the last element.  Add an element, edit the last, add another element, edit the last, etc.  Is there a way to do that?  Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: @kroe761 provide more info of what you are trying to do. You want to test <select> html-elements? In turn? Select first and check its value then second?

Comment: Sorry - I am testing my company's customer service call center software in our test environment.  I am adding products to the cart and trying to edit the address.  By default, when Selenium is recording, and I change an address, the captured target is id=address_menu_7174004 (or some other number).  I have used the xpath //*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")] which successfully targets the first element, but not the rest of them.  For the test I am trying to run, I need to be able to change all of the addresses.  I tried your suggestion of //*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")][8]...

Comment: but that did not work.  I also tried //*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")][last()], but that successfulyl targeted the first dropdown box, not the last.  At this point, I am stuck.  I do QA for my company, and am trying to learn more about programming, but as of yet I am still very new and can't figure this one out.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that there are exactly 8 dropboxes? May be 7 or 6? I don't have an idea why `//*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")][8]` does not work except that there may be less than 8 items. Are they <selects>? Provide some html to see what the actual structure of the document

Comment: I added the HTML in the body of the original question.  I can promise that there are eight elements - four products, and four gift announcements :-)

Comment: Here is the error message from Selenium I received - `[error] Element //*[contains(@id, "address_menu_")][2] not found`

Comment: @kroe761 so how is your trouble? If that did not help, then, please, paste all of the html to jsfiddle, you can do this by pressing Ctrl + U to view html-source (in Firefox at least).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<tr>
    <td>addSelection</td>
    <td>Locate your select element</td>
    <td>Option you need to select</td>
</tr>
```